# A Riddle to be found

Tags: riddle

> "The spinning webb of time knitted in vacuum seeks its centre."

(It's not a black hole.)

The answer can be one or two words, but won't exceed that. That's all the hints!

I ventured this question in an exam. It was nice; all teams were stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> The sun?

The spinning webb of time

> the orbit of the James Webb telescope

knitted in vacuum

> the vacuum of space

seeks its centre

> it orbits the sun

Comment: A quick google search (spoiler: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ph5R58gc31s) made me think you're on to something and that the question should have had the knowledge tag.

Answer (score 0):

> Crochet doily?

Because

> They're visibly weblike.  Not technically knitted, but damn close.  And if you pull on a loose thread it will unravel in a spiral towards the centre.